# Docker with Angular - Docker Builds Large Image File

Tags: angular, docker, angular-cli

I created a new project using `Angular CLI` and tried to set the project up with Docker.

After successfully building the image using `docker build`, it seems that the image size isn't normal having `1.33GB`.

[image]

Also tried to `ssh` onto my container and it shows `499M`

[image]

Here's my `Docker` file:

```
FROM node:9.5.0

ENV HOME=/usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p $HOME
WORKDIR $HOME

COPY ./package.json $HOME
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . $HOME

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Is there a way to reduce the image size?

***Why do I need to reduce the image size?*** 

No particular reason. The size just doesn't seem normal for such a small project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `alpine` version of `node` decreases the size significantly.

`Dockerfile`:
`FROM node:9.5.0-alpine`

Size reduced from `1.33GB` down to `720MB`